# Download a file using Downloads.jsm fetch with progress

Tags: download, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to switch over from `nsWebBrowserPersist.saveURI()` to `Downloads.jsm`'s [`Downloads.fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm#fetch%28%29) but i couldn't find a way to monitor the file download progress yet, is there one?

In the [createDownload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm#createDownload%28%29) documentation they are talking about a `DownloadSaver` object, but i can't find any further documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Promise` returned by `createDownload()` resolves to a `Download` object.

If this object's `hasProgress` property is `true`, then you can consult the `progress` property for a valid percent indicator of the progress (0-100).